# Determining $L_z$ eigenvalues via superposition of eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

This is exercise 12.3.2. from Shankar's 'Principles of Quantum Mechanics'

> Part 1: "By considering the superposition of two allowed $l_{z}$ eigenstates $$\psi(\rho,\phi)=A(\rho)e^{i\phi l_{z}/\hbar}+B(\rho)e^{i\phi l'_{z}/\hbar}$$
> and by demanding that upon a $2\pi$ rotation we get the same physical state show that $l_{z} - l'_{z} = m\hbar$, where $m$ is an integer."

> Part 2: "By arguing on the grounds of symmetry that the allowed values of $m$ must be symmetric about zero, show that the values of $l_{z}$ are either $...,3\hbar/2, \hbar/2, -\hbar/2, -3\hbar/2,...$ or $...,2\hbar, \hbar, 0, -\hbar, -2\hbar,...$It is not possible to further restrict $l_{z}$ this way."

I can do Part 1 without any issues but I am stumped on Part 2. The possible $l_{z}$ values $...,3\hbar/2, \hbar/2, -\hbar/2, -3\hbar/2,...$ appear to correspond to $l'_{z} = -l_{z}$ and the possible values $...,2\hbar, \hbar, 0, -\hbar, -2\hbar,...$ appear to correspond to $l'_{z} = 0$. So my question is how do I show that these are the only values that $l'_{z}$ can take? Why can we not have $l'_{z} = \alpha l_{z}$ where $\alpha$ could be any constant as long as $l_{z} - l'_{z} = m\hbar$?

Answer (score 0):

If the allowed values of $l_z$ are symmetric about zero, then for any allowed $l_z$ we must also have that $-l_z$ is permitted.  However, as per point 1, these values must differ by an integer.  What does that tell you about the allowed values of $l_z$?

Comment: Then we would have $l_{z} + l_{z} = m\hbar$ so $l_{z} = m\hbar/2$. But how do we know that $l_{z}$ is symmetric about zero? Also if our eigenvalues symmetric about zero are say for example $l_{z}, -l_{z}, 2l_{z}, -2l_{z}$, what's to stop us from having $l_{z} -(-2l_{z}) = m\hbar$ so $l_{z} = m\hbar/3$?

Comment: @Nitram That's the symmetry argument you're supposed to make.  Ask yourself - what's special about choosing the $z$-axis to be pointing up?  Why can't you do physics standing on your head, so the $z$-axis is pointing the other way around?

Comment: OK that makes sense that $l_{z}$ should be symmetric. So in the example I gave above I'm guessing that it doesn't make sense to talk about $2l_{z}$ and $-2l_{z}$, there is only $l_{z}$ and $-l_{z}$?

Comment: @Nitram It makes sense to talk about $2l_z$ and $-2l_z$.  It **doesn't** make sense to talk about $l_z$ and $-2l_z$, because those two values are not related to one another by spatial inversion (which is the symmetry we're trying to exploit).  Therefore, there is no basis on which to argue that if $l_z$ is an allowed value, then $-2l_z$ is an allowed value.